# Flattened Point Cloud to Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, point-clouds

I have a flattened point cloud (x,y) that I have displayed in a scatter plot (just 10 points for simplicity sake):

[image]

Here are the x and y values:

```
x_data = [2.36412072, 2.3787694,  2.39039516, 2.40705276, 3.25796771, 3.26817608, 3.27696705, 3.28460264, 3.28830409, 3.29867196]
y_data = [5.97259283, 5.97819757, 5.9762435,  5.98669958, 5.79369593, 5.78980064, 5.78343678, 5.77508879, 5.75993538, 5.75646544]
```

Each of these points have a pixel value associated with them. How would I go about creating an IMAGE that has the same dimensions as the scatter plot, but with the points displaying lets say black, and all the rest of the space be white.
Ultimately this will be for 100k+ points. The more points used the clearer the image.

Any help would greatly be apprecaited.

Comment: create a [csr_sparse_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), and convert it later to dense matrix to get what you want.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at it now. can you maybe elaborate what the shape would be? The examples have a given shape, where this would need some sort of grid....

Comment: There is two choices: either you multiply the X,Y values by 10^n to make all of them integers, then the shape will be (max value in X, max value in Y) after making them large integers, or you have to sacrifice with some precision of the coordinates of your point to reduce the size of the resultant matrix, then you will get a smaller matrix.

Comment: *"IMAGE that has the same dimensions as the scatter plot"* I'm not sure if this is achievable, because the size of the image will be in TeraBytes maybe!

Comment: Yes. The next goal would be to be able to partition the full image out to look at smaller chunks.

Comment: All the points construct multiple images stitched together. Was trying to get a comprehensive image of all the images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213719/discussion-between-belal-homaidan-and-lr100).